# Can there be more than one values of condition codes?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

For example, for

```
movq 30, rax
subq 10, rax
subq 20, rax
```

Can the condition codes be something else other than ZF = 1 and SF = 0, because rax = 0?

Comment: This code will always produce that. Of course you can have zero in `rax` with any combinations of flags but you need different code for that.

Comment: flags ZF=1 and SF=0 are not because `rax` is 0, but because the result of `sub` was zero (and stored to `rax`). If you would start with ZF=0 and do `mov $0, eax`, you would end with `rax = 0` too, but ZF would be unaffected (because `mov` does not affect flags). BTW you are missing `$` for your immediate values, if this is supposed to be AT&T syntax.